# ¿Por qué me retorna siempre true el método?

Tags: java, switch

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual me dice si un vehículo está en pico y placa(no puede salir a la calle), esto lo hago con un switch. El problema viene a la hora de ejecutar el programa, puesto que al hacerlo, el método en el cual verifico esto, siempre me devuelve true, cuando en ocasiones me debería devolver un false.

### Caso de prueba

Ejemplo: si la placa es CAM129, me debería devolver false.

### Notas

las listas que cree, son respecto a cada dia de la semana, ya que cada dia tiene dos numeros los cuales me definen si el vehiculo esta o no en pico y placa.Está en pico y placa si el último número de la placa es uno de esos dos. También agrego que al intentar hacerlo manualmente, es decir, sin las listas, colocando los números tal cual, funciona correctamente, el problema es que requiero que esten en una lista.

### Código fuente

Este es el código:

```
public class Restriction {
    List<Integer>monday = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer>tuesday = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer>wednesday = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer>thursday = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer>friday = new ArrayList<>();

public void picoPlaca(){
    monday.add(6,9);
    tuesday.add(5,7);
    wednesday.add(1,4);
    thursday.add(8,0);
    friday.add(3,2);
}

public boolean restrictionCar(Vehicle vehicle){
    
    vehicle.day = vehicle.getDayOfWeek(new Date()); /*vehicle.day tiene el dia de la semana*/
    
    int numCar = vehicle.getPlate().charAt(5); /*numCar tiene el ultimo numero de placa*/
    
    switch(vehicle.day){
        case "lunes" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<monday.size();i++){
                if(numCar == monday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        
        case "martes" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<tuesday.size();i++){
                if(numCar == tuesday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "miercoles" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<wednesday.size();i++){
                if(numCar == wednesday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "jueves" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<thursday.size();i++){
                if(numCar == thursday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "viernes" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<friday.size();i++){
                if(numCar == friday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "sabado" -> {
            return true;
        }
        case "domingo" -> {
            return true;
        }
        default -> {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public boolean restrictionMotorcycle(Vehicle vehicle){
    
    char numMotorcycle = vehicle.getPlate().charAt(3);
    
    vehicle.day = vehicle.getDayOfWeek(new Date());
    
   switch(vehicle.day){
        case "lunes" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<monday.size();i++){
                if(numMotorcycle == monday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "martes" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<tuesday.size();i++){
                if(numMotorcycle == tuesday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "miercoles" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<wednesday.size();i++){
                if(numMotorcycle == wednesday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "jueves" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<thursday.size();i++){
                if(numMotorcycle == thursday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "viernes" -> {
            for(int i=0;i<friday.size();i++){
                if(numMotorcycle == friday.get(i)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        case "sabado" -> {
            return true;
        }
        case "domingo" -> {
            return true;
        }
        default -> {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Vehicle {

private String plate;
private String vehicleType;
private Date dateEntry;
public String day;


public String getDayOfWeek(Date date) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Estás validando, por ejemplo,  contra el char `9`. Yo haría que ambos fueran Integer antes de comparar cosas.

Comment: Intente cambiando ambos a char y después con int, pero sigue dando el mismo resultado

Comment: Eh, no es que no te creamos pero, por favor, ve a [edit] y muéstranos cómo lo intentaste. Puede haber un error de implementación, tipográfico, etc.

Comment: Listo, ahi puedes ver como lo intente

Comment: no entiendo la placa de ejemplo, CAM129 que dias es pico y cuales placa?

Comment: pq inicias una instancia de `Date` en el método `getDayOfWeek` de la clase `Veicles`?, si la fecha no coincide cuando la evalúas en el `switch` case retornara diferentes resultados no esperados/deseados.

Comment: @Ruslan López CAM129 no podria circular el dia lunes, porque los dias lunes, las placas que terminen con un 9 o 6 no podran circular. El pico y placa es una medida que restringe la circulación de los vehiculos, por ende no hay vehiculos pico o placa. El pico y placa simplemente es una medida.

Comment: @user327285 El problema no radica en el dia de la semana, ese está bien, lo comprobe sacando el valor por pantalla. El problema está en que el for que está dentro del switch siempre me retorna true

Comment: nunca dije que el problema radicara alli

Answer (score 1):

Creo que retorna `true` ya que durante las iteraciones es posible que no retorne nada, pero puedes intentar definir una variable `condicion` y si el vehículo coincide pues cambiar su valor y usar `break` para detener el ciclo y retornar el valor esperado.

```
boolean condicion = true; 
switch(vehicle.day){
    case "lunes" -> {
        for(int i=0;i<monday.size();i++){
            if(numCar == monday.get(i)){
                condicion = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return condicion;
    }
// ...
```

También noto que al compilar el código usando `dia_de_la_semanada.add(int, int)` devuelve un error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 0
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:755)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:480)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Pero al llamarlo para cada digito separado funciona correctamente.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer>monday = new ArrayList<>();
        tuesday.add(1);
        tuesday.add(1);
        for (int i : monday) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }    
    }
}
```

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

hay partes de tu código que no entiendo, pero vamos "a los bifes", donde tu código falla.

```
public void picoPlaca() {
    monday.add( 6, 9 );
    tuesday.add( 5, 7 );
    wednesday.add( 1, 4 );
    thursday.add( 8, 0 );
    friday.add( 3, 2 );
}
```

La linea **monday.add( 6, 9 );** (y las similares) arrojan un error, ya que no se pueden agregar varias variables a un **List**, las opciones son:

```
monday.add( 6 );
monday.add( 9 );
```

o bien:

```
monday = List.of( 6, 9 );
```

quedaría así:

```
public void picoPlaca() {
    monday = List.of( 6, 9 );
    tuesday = List.of( 5, 7 );
    wednesday = List.of( 1, 4 );
    thursday = List.of( 8, 0 );
    friday = List.of( 3, 2 );
}
```

Para probar, tuve que inventarme cosas, no se si hay otros errores en el código, pero al menos ten la seguridad de que con esta insignificante modificación, el método **restrictionCar** y el hermano, funcionan.

Algunas veces los errores son tan insignificantes, que encontrarlos, se convierte en una odisea...

El método **getDayOfWeek**, me está devolviendo ***miércoles*** y tu **case** dice ***miercoles*** un acento de diferencia y cataplum...

Por otro lado, la linea

```
int numCar = vehicle.getPlate().charAt(5);
```

es errónea, el método **charrAt()** devuelve el valor numérico de un caracter (por ejemplo, si mal no recuerdo, a la letra "A" le corresponde el valor "65") lo que claramente invalida tu código, cambiamos por

```
int numCar = Integer.parseInt( vehicle.getPlate().substring( 5, 6 ));
```

y de repente, el mundo es un lugar maravilloso...

Comment: Hola Marce, primero que todo, muchas gracias por tu aporte. Intente hacer lo que dijiste pero sigue sin funcionar, siempre me retorna true, lo raro es que para comprobar mostre los valores de cada lista en el for y me muestra correctamente sus numeros, lo mismo con numCar, me muestra correctamente el numero que guarde, por eso mismo no comprendo por qué siempre me retorna el true, cuando deberia retornar false.

Comment: Dale, ahi agregue la clase Vehiculo, en notas tambien agregue un poquito de info

Comment: Solucionadoooo!!!

Comment: Hola Marce, lamento informate que sigue sin funcionar :(. Hice todo tal cual pero siempre me sigue retornando true. Tambien intente cambiando el numCar a char pero sigue exactamente igual

Comment: Hola Camilo, perdón por la ausencia, cuando yo pongo "solucionado", eso quiere decir que he copiado tu código a mi máquina, he realizado las correcciones pertinentes, lo he ejecutado, y ha funcionado, esto nos lleva al que creo que es el único escenario posible, que estén llegando mal los datos, te sugiero que coloques antes del "switch" **Sytem.out.println( numCar );** y **Sytem.out.println( vehicle.day );**, y verifiques que correspondan a lo que esperas... perdona la pregunta boba... sabes que el código así como está, solo dará "false" si lo ejecutas un día miércoles? (por la patente).